# Finding time complexity in terms of n

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
class test_case
{
  public static void test(int n)
  {
    int sum=0;int i;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(;i<n*n;i++)
       {
          sum=sum+i;
       }
    }
    system.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is you attempt at calculating the complexity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop runs `n²` times, while the outher loop runs just `1` time, since at its first iteration `i` already reaches `n²`, so it violates the loop condition.

Thus, the total complexity is `1 * n²` = `n²`.

Comment: Nitpicking but the inner loop runs `(n² - i)` times. But since it only runs once it runs `(n² - 1)` times.